# TradingView indicator moves to the right after migrating a version 2 pinescipt to version 4

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=2
study(title="Test", shorttitle="Test", overlay=true)
LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M = input("30")
Range2 = input(1)
SELL = security(tickerid, LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M, highest(Range2))
BUY = security(tickerid, LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M, lowest(Range2))
HI = plot(SELL, color=SELL!=SELL[1]?na:red,linewidth=2 )
LO = plot(BUY, color=BUY!=BUY[1]?na:green,linewidth=2 )
fill(HI, LO, color=#E3CAF1, transp=100)
```

This script creates automated support and resistance lines in the chart like the "Evan Cabral Binary Strategy" indicator does. Here is a screenshot how it does and should look like:
[TradingView-chart with pinescript v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsW1g.png)

I want to migrate this script to PineScript Verion 4. I have changed `tickerid` to `syminfo.tickerid`, the colors to `color.red`, and `//@version=2` to `//@version=4`. If I compile the script no errors occur. Here is the new script:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Test", shorttitle="Test", overlay=true)
LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M = input("30")
Range2 = input(1)
SELL = security(syminfo.tickerid, LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M, highest(Range2))
BUY = security(syminfo.tickerid, LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M, lowest(Range2))
HI = plot(SELL, color=SELL!=SELL[1]?na:color.red,linewidth=2 )
LO = plot(BUY, color=BUY!=BUY[1]?na:color.green,linewidth=2 )
fill(HI, LO, color=#E3CAF1, transp=100)
```

But the support and resistance lines which you can see in the screenshot from above moves for them own length to the right. Now it looks like this: [TradingView-chart with pinescript v4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC99W.png)

I watched many video tutorials and so on but I am still a beginner in PineScript and don't know how to solve that. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add parameter `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` to your `security()` calls.
If you want an in-depth explanation on how `security()` calls work, you should check out [security() revisited by [PineCoders]](https://www.tradingview.com/script/00jFIl5w-security-revisited-PineCoders/)

```
//@version=4
study(title="Test", shorttitle="Test", overlay=true)

LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M = input("30")
Range2 = input(1)

SELL = security(syminfo.tickerid, LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M, highest(Range2), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
BUY = security(syminfo.tickerid, LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M, lowest(Range2), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

HI = plot(SELL, color=SELL!=SELL[1]?na:color.red,linewidth=2 )
LO = plot(BUY, color=BUY!=BUY[1]?na:color.green,linewidth=2 )

fill(HI, LO, color=#E3CAF1, transp=100)
```